# TypeScript: Sometimes don't show the latest data when delete user

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on chrome browser. I have a table list users, and want to CRUD on that. Try to delete user, sometimes data reload is OK, but sometimes it's not change (need to press f5, the page will show latest data) 
In ts file:

```
 deleteUser(user: User) {
    if(user){
      this.userService.deleteUser(user);
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
  }

 ngOnInit() { //when component loading get all users and set the users[]
    this.getAllUsers();  
  }

 getAllUsers() {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(user =>
        this.users = user
       );

  }
```

service

```
deleteUser(user: User): Promise<void> {
        const url = `${this.userUrl}/${user.id}`;
        return this.http.delete(url, { headers: this.headers })
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => null)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

 getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.userUrl)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json().content as User[])
          .catch(this.handleError)
      }
```

html

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button>
```

Please advice me. Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you executing `this.ngOnInit()` instead of `this.getAllUsers()`?

Comment: @DGarvanski: this is an simple example. I think it will save more time when I change a lot of data table (eg: getAllUsers(), getAllRoles(), GetAllCountry(),...)

Comment: What I would suggest is putting all the `getAllSomething()` methods in a method of their own and use that. Otherwise, you're just messing with the lifecycle of the component.

Comment: @DGarvanski: thank you for your suggestion, I will try it. I'm learning typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
  async deleteUser(user: User): Promise<void>  {
    if(user){
      await this.userService.deleteUser(user);
      await this.getAllUsers();
    }
  }
```

Notice that calling `ngOnInit` hook manually has a smell, also `ngOnInit` doesn't return a promise, so there would be race conditions too when `deleteUser` is called by other means than `click` event (including tests).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
this.userService.deleteUser(user);
this.ngOnInit();
```

should be something like

```
this.userService.deleteUser(user).then(res => this.ngOnInit());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteUser(user: User) {
    if(user){
      this.userService.deleteUser(user)
           .then(() => this.ngOnInit());
    }
  }
```

The deleteUser function service is returning a promise so you need to call onInit only after the promise is resolved.